# Why does R order function not work on this dataframe -- returns only first (unsorted) value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe holding survey results with the following columns:

```
 1) number of unanswered questions, 
 2) number of times the respondent answered with the most common (consensus) response, 
 3) number of questions answered, and 
 4) the percentage of questions in which the respondent answered with the consensus response.
```

I want to sort this by the last column (percent consensus answers) and select the highest quintile.  I can't seem to sort it, though.

Here's the str():

```
> str(consensus_participant_totals)
'data.frame':   210 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1           : Factor w/ 210 levels "R_06xJVSOuTuhYLOt",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ num_nas      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ num_cons     : num  61 61 54 54 52 55 57 52 41 60 ...
 $ num_answered : num  68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 ...
 $ pct_consensus: num  0.868 0.794 0.735 0.809 0.779 ...
```

Here's the first few lines:

```
consensus_participant_totals
                   V1 num_nas num_cons num_answered pct_consensus
1   R_06xJVSOuTuhYLOt       0       61           68     0.8676471
2   R_09aLjPFNmYMmsbX       0       61           68     0.7941176
3   R_0AphAH5kJRGOFfL       0       54           68     0.7352941
4   R_0cTBiuOmRWuFCZL       0       54           68     0.8088235
5   R_0dBEYzi8C7A65P7       0       52           68     0.7794118
6   R_0dCNkauEqyd2Y97       0       55           68     0.8529412
```

when I try:

```
consensus_participant_totals[order(pct_consensus),]
```

I get

```
Error in order(pct_consensus) : object 'pct_consensus' not found
```

which suggests that I have to put it in quotes (which nobody seems to do in the examples -- I don't get why)

when I try it with quotes, I just get the first row:

```
consensus_participant_totals[order("pct_consensus"),]             
                V1 num_nas num_cons num_answered pct_consensus
1 R_06xJVSOuTuhYLOt       0       61           68     0.8676471
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I sort by "pct_consensus"

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Whoop.  Solved it myself.  The answer was:   c2<-consensus_participant_totals[order(c(consensus_participant_totals[,"pct_consensus"])),]

Comment: Most people initially assume that the evaluation frame for expressions inside the "[" function will be determined by the first argument (which in usual notation is the object to the left of the operator, `consensus_participant_totals` her). That's just not how the language was designed. It is how the "[" operator works in the data.table package.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you can't call a column without specifying the data frame. Using a built-in data example (both so anyone can run it and because it has a lot fewer characters in the name):

Everyone has the `iris` data set:

```
head(iris)
```

The first column is `Sepal.Length`, it's in the data set but not in your workspace except as part of the data set

```
head(iris$Sepal.Length)
head(iris[, "Sepal.Length"])
head(Sepal.Length) # error, no Sepal.Length
```

So, when you sort based on a column, you must tell R where the column is. There are many ways to do this:

```
iris[order(iris$Sepal.Length), ]
iris[order(iris[, "Sepal.Length"]), ]
iris[order(iris["Sepal.Length"]), ]
with(iris, iris[order(Sepal.Length), ])
```

But it can't be ignored

```
iris[order(Sepal.Length), ]  # errors out
```

In figuring out things like this, remember that you can run tiny snippets of R code. You say

```
> when I try it with quotes, I just get the first row:

consensus_participant_totals[order("pct_consensus"),]
```

This is because your ordering a character vector of length 1. If you run

```
order("pct_consensus")
```

It's equivalent to these

```
order("a")
order("whatever string you put here")
```

They return 1, because your asking "If I sort a single string alphabetically, what position should it be in?" With only one string, the answer is always 1. So that's why you get the first row.

Comment: Thanks.  When I looked at the tutorials, I overlooked that all of the examples had "attached" the dataframe.

Comment: Yeah. `attach`ing is a nasty habit that should be avoided. Does much more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing around, it worked with the following:

```
c2 <-consensus_participant_totals[c(order(consensus_participant_totals[,"pct_consensus"])),]
```

It seems I can put the concat either before or after the order function (e.g. c(order(consensus_... or order(c(consensus... in the above

This does not look a bit like most of the tutorials.  I think my error was in that most of the tutorials use the "attach" function, which avoids having to put the dataframe name in the command, and I ignored that.  Thus, simply doing (for dataframe x) x[order(y),] won't work because I didn't attach x.

I think....

Comment: Your `c()` does nothing in this code... `c(1)` is equivalent to `1`.

Comment: Which I guess is why it makes no difference :-)